# Get black screen at logon/welcome?

Tags: windows-7, display, blank-screen

I turn on my computer and screen seems to be working, but as soon as it comes to the screen where I am suppose to put in my password I get a black screen, except for the momentary message from monitor: "no connection, check cables"?

I have gotten it to work by first plugging it into my old monitor, which works fine, then without unplugging it from the computer, then plugging the cable into my new (bigger) monitor. That's all great except I can't display in 1920x1080 because my old monitor doesn't support that resolution and it still thinks its outputting to my old monitor (I checked it's properties to verify), so I have about 2 inches on each side that are black. Mainly it is just annoying to have to plug/unplug 50 cords just to get it working again if I restart my computer or open my graphics card control center.

I have tried disabling driver signing, playing with DDC/CI (on/off), booting in low-res/safe-mode (I did get it to work for a while, but couldn't get it to stay that way, so may be a clue), running the driver installation in compatibility mode (XP and Vista), updating video-card/monitor drivers, but no avail! I am so frustrated. I tried contacting the manufacturer and they did try to answer my questions, but their suggestions were pretty much worthless. After about 10 email replies I just gave up trying to cooperate with them because they clearly hadn't any idea how to fix the issue or didn't want to admit it was not going to work?

Also, I checked the H/V values as different resolutions (when it would let me...when it looses connection it won't let me look at those settings) and got these values for 1360x768 and 1920x1080, respectively: [47.82khz, 60.2hz}, {67.8,60.3}. Furthermore, my old computer is a VGA connection so I must use a VGA to "trick" it into displaying. If I turn off the computer, unplug VGA, plug in HDMI -> DVI, then turn it back on, then I am able to see splash screen (the one that tells you what buttons to push for bios, etc...), then when gets to logon screen it goes blank, as I mentioned already. Well sorry this had to be so long...I just wanted to give as many clues in the most precise way so that hopefully someone somewhere can help me fix this piece of shiz monitor! *_*

Computer Specs:
-25in Hannspree monitor (HF259H)
-Windows 7 (64bit)
-ATI Radeon 6950
-8gb RAM
-AMD Phenom X6

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the well detailed question.

It seems to me that the Windows 7 monitor settings have been misconfigured. Try going into safe-mode again, and then change any settings (like resolution, etc.) to compatible settings for the monitor. Maby even try setting it to 800x600. Also, in the "Screen resolution" window, click "Advanced settings". Now go to the "Monitor" tab. There, make sure the "Screen refresh rate" is set correctly. You might try to briefly set it lower, then back to the value it was at, so that Windows saves that setting. (ex: If it's at 60, change it to 50, then click Apply, and click OK on the confirmation. Then change it back to 60, and do the same.).
**Remember: If changing the refresh rate or resolution also turns off the monitor (no signal, etc.), then wait 15 seconds for Windows to change it back!**
[image: Screen resolution and refresh rate.]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I attempted that already, but I will try again, carefully following your instructions. If I can remember right, I could change resolution, but after restarting the computer I got a blank screen again anyhow....Again, thanks for the detailed answer! :)

Comment: Thanks, and I think it's smarter if you just vote my answer up, and mark it as the answer only if it actually worked, so others will still attempt to help :)

Answer (score 0):

i just found out the answer after 5 hours of headache to figure what is going with my computer. I'm not the computer expert but you can try this.

Press F8 at boot start, on Screen got SafeMode, SafeMode with network, etc.

Click on Last Known Good Configuration (advance).
Be happy like me.

Comment: Thanks, I have already tried this, but hopefully it helps someone in the future? Currently, I just make sure the monitor is totally unplugged before turning my computer on or off and it seems to work (and make sure never to click "detect new hardware" or change the resolution...lol