# Black Screen On XP Guest

Tags: windows-xp, troubleshooting, vmware-player

[image: Loading]
[Full size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIjX9.jpg)

I'm running Windows XP as guest on VMware Player 6.0.1, but I'm getting a black screen. The VM starts up, I 
see the XP logo screen as it loads, but then the welcome screen never appears.

[image: Black screen]
[Full size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94StT.png)

It's worth noting that this VM is running inside another VM running a Windows XP guest; the outer-host is Windows 8. 
Everything is responsive, I can move the innermost-machine window around, even resize it, but it won't display 
the welcome screen.

[image: Repsonsive, and resizable]
[Full size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgVKf.png)

According to ( [Ubuntu 11.04 VM shows a black screen in VMware Player](https://superuser.com/questions/339873/ubuntu-11-04-vm-shows-a-black-screen-in-vmware-player) ) and
( [Issue while loading vmware fusion 3.0](https://superuser.com/questions/423740/issue-while-loading-vmware-fusion-3-0) ), enabling hardware graphics 
acceleration may fix black-screen issues for some guests, but my VMs already have it enabled, and my screen doesn't
start black, it goes black, so I don't think it's the same issue. I've also looked at ( [Get black screen at logon/welcome?](https://superuser.com/questions/267779/get-black-screen-at-logon-welcome) ), but as I've shown in my screenshot, adjusting the screen resolution of the guest doesn't help.

What is the problem here, and if it's fixable, how so?

Please, no harsh-comments along the lines of "don't run a VM in a VM!!!". I'm aware it's not a recommended activity, 
this is just for fun.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Virtual Machine Settings of the guest that is blank, under Hardware, Display, try turning off Accelerate 3D graphics.

When I have the box on, under Linux Mint 16 (ubuntu), the guest will be black on every screen except the main screen--unless I turn off the 3D acceleration as noted above.

Answer (score 0):

### Why do VMWare virtual machines stay on a black screen on start?

When starting a VM, VMWare will try to connect to this address (which is localhost in IPv6 format on ports like 11527 or 11535 etc.):

`vmware.exe - [::1]:11535 (IPv6)`

This is needed for the VMs to work, I don't know what it is, but I just know that my VPN, and one other time, my proxy, were *blocking* vmware from establishing this connection, thus I was getting the black screen issue.

[image: Proxifier]

So I turned off the VPN, and in the second case which I was using Proxifier, I added a rule inside the Proxifier program to *direct* all `vmware.exe` connections (not route them to proxy server), and the problem was resolved.

Issue also reported and discussed here: https://communities.vmware.com/thread/454006

[image: vmware]